# React Router gives 404 if I try to copy and paste url in new tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router, webpack-dev-server

I am not sure if react router is not working correctly or if I am missing something.

I have something like this

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider  } from 'mobx-react';
import { configure } from 'mobx';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import {syncHistoryWithStore } from 'mobx-react-router';
import { Router } from 'react-router'

import AppContainer from './components/App';

const browserHistory = createBrowserHistory();

import stores from '../src/stores/Stores';

const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, stores.routingStore);

configure({ enforceActions: true});

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider {... stores}>
        <Router history={history}>
           <AppContainer />
        </Router>
    </Provider>,      
       document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Then in my AppContainer I have this

```
import { withRouter, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
<Route path="/company-details/company/:companyId/employee/:employeeId" component={CompanyComponent} />
```

and

```
   <Link to="/company-details/company/76/employee/77"></Link>
```

now when I click on the link, it goes to the right page and I got access to the parameters.

but say if I did ctrl + click to make a new tab while clicking on the link or refreshing the page.

I get

```
GET http://localhost:8080/company-details/company/76/employee/index_bundle.js 404 (Not Found)

Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8080/company-details/company/76/employee/index_bundle.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

I have these packages installed

```
"react-router-dom": "^4.2.2"
 "mobx-react-router": "^4.0.4",
```

Edit

my webpack.config

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: ["babel-polyfill", "./src/index.js"],

  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "/dist"),
    filename: "index_bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /(\.css|\.scss|\.sass)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
          },
          {
            loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
          },
          {
            loader: "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {}  
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html"
    })
  ],
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
  }
};
```

Comment: How you link your javascript file in HTML file?

Comment: It's all handled by webpack but essentially it makes this: <script type="text/javascript" src="index_bundle.js"></script></body>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `index.html` you should link your script file like following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./index_bundle.js"></script>
```

Comment: `/index_bundle.js`, not `./index_bundle.js`. You want to use an absolute path so that the JS isn't a relative URL from the document's URL.

Comment: How do I control what webpack  spits out. In dev mode I don't even see the html file.